# QFile from native handle

Tags: c++, qt

Можно ли создать QFile из уже имеющегося "родного" дескриптора файла?

```
QFile qt_file;
HANDLE win_file = CreateFile(<file_path>, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, NULL);

if (win_file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || win_file == NULL)
{
     // Erorr here
}
else
{
    qt_file =// QFile::from_native_handle(win_file) ?
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191480/how-to-get-a-windows-handle-from-a-qfile-or-qsavefile-for-reopenfile

Comment: @arrowd, нет, мне надо наоборот сделать QFile из HANDLE

Comment: В последней части ответа есть код, который делает это.